# Get QuotaTemplateName from SPSite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a script updating users `-QutaTemplate` when the default quota is changed.

But the problem is that it's also updating users who have individual quotas set. How can I get the name of the `QuotaTemplate` that is used on each user in the `foreach` loop, to skip those?

This is my current script:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://xxx.xxx.xxx

foreach($site in $webApp.Sites) {   

    # Skip the root url
    if($site.Url -eq "http://xxx.xxx.xxx") {
        continue
    }

    Write-Host $site.Url
    Set-SPSite -Identity $site.Url -QuotaTemplate “Quota Name”
    $site.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Id of the quota from the Quota property on the SPSite object. You can get the name from the Administration service:

```
$quotaId = $site.Quota
$cs =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$quotaName = $($cs.QuotaTemplates | Where {$_.QuotaID -eq $quotaId}).Name
```

Comment: Just one edit to your code, in the first line, you need to add .QuotaID ($site.Quota.QuotaID).